# Device-agnostic context for rendering with OpenGL in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qwidget, qimage

I have some code that uses QPainter to render to a QWidget, QImage or QPrinter, since each is derived from QPaintDevice, like this:

```
void RenderWithQPainter (QPaintDevice* device)
{
    QPainter painter (device);
    painter->doThis();
    painter->doThat();
}

void RenderToImage (QImage* image)
{
    RenderWithQPainter (image);
}

void RenderToWidget (QWidget* widget)
{
    RenderWithQPainter (widget);
}
void RenderToPrinter (QPrinter* printer)
{
    RenderWithQPainter (printer);
}
```

Now though, I want to use OpenGL.  I know how to render into a QOpelGLWidget but I'd like my code to remain device-agnostic.  So what can I render into that I can then copy to the various devices?  Is there something I could derive from each of QWidget, QImage and QPrinter, not necessarily a Qt class, which I could render to using OpenGL commands instead of QPainter?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the combination of 'device-agnostic' and `OpenGL`.  However, it sounds like you might want to [render to a texture using a framebuffer object](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers).

Comment: And then use glReadPixels e.g. to construct e.g. a QPixmap or QImage?

Comment: Ok, your last  changes things and I suspect I've misunderstood the question.  You might want to have a look at [`QOpenGLPaintDevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglpaintdevice.html).  I've never used it but without a more complete code example showing what you're doing with OpenGL all I can really do is guess.